# Anaconda Error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 321: invalid start byte

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I am trying to train an image data set on anaconda. It gives that error on view_image function at for loop:

"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 321: invalid start byte"
I tried it on my laptop, it runs correctly. What can i do? I cant load data as utf-8 because it is image. I added it anyway but it gave the same error

```
image_dir = 'D:/db/BreaKHis_v1/'
data_path = 'D:/db/Folds.csv'
tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
data = pd.read_csv(data_path)
.
.
.
# sorting out training, validation and testing images
test_images = data.groupby(by='label').sample(3000)
train_images = data.drop(test_images.index).reset_index(drop=True)
test_images = test_images.reset_index(drop=True)
# making splits of training & validation datasets
validation_images = train_images.sample(frac = 0.3)
train_images = train_images.drop(validation_images.index).reset_index(drop=True)
validation_images = validation_images.reset_index(drop=True)
print('Total training images: % s' % str(train_images.shape[0]))
print('Total validation images: % s' % str(validation_images.shape[0]))
print('Total testing images: % s' % str(test_images.shape[0]))
train_images['set'] = 'train'
validation_images['set'] = 'validation'
test_images['set'] = 'test'
new_data = pd.concat([train_images, validation_images, test_images])
.
.
.
# function to view sample of images
def view_image(ds, col = 5, row = 5, size=(30, 10)):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.05, hspace = 0.15)
    for images, labels in ds.take(1):  ----> gives error on this line
        for i in range(col * row):
            ax = plt.subplot(row, col, i + 1)
            shape = str(images[i].numpy().shape)
            plt.imshow(images[i].numpy())
            plt.title(class_names[labels[i].numpy()])
            plt.axis("off") 
    plt.tight_layout
    return None

# defining model configuration parameters
model_name = "efficientnetv2-b0"
# model_name = "inception_v3"
# model_name = "inception_resnet_v2"
model_handle = model_handle_map.get(model_name)
IMG_SIZE = model_image_size.get(model_name, 224)
BATCH_SIZE = 32
EPOCHS = 10
sample_size = len(train_images)
# loading the train & validation dataets
load_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_dir + train_images.path, 
                                                train_images.label_int))

load_valid = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_dir + validation_images.path, 
                                                validation_images.label_int))
train_dataset = (
                load_train.shuffle(len(train_images))
                .map(load_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
                .map(partial(argumentor_function), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
                .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
                .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
                )
val_dataset = (
                load_valid.shuffle(len(validation_images))
                .map(load_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
                .map(partial(argumentor_function), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
                .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
                .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
                )

train_dataset

start = time.time()
view_image(train_dataset)  -------------------->Gives error on this line
end = time.time()
print('Time Taken: %.3f seconds' % (end-start))
```

Comment: try data = pd.read_csv(data_path,encoding='utf-8')

Comment: I tried it. Did not work